# 'dar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, runtime-error

I created the new Flutter project on android studio. Then I try to run it but it gives this error. My previous projects are running properly. If anyone can solve this?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 9 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
'dar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Then try `flutter run` result is same

```
PS E:\Intern\26-light & dar theme\untitled1> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 9 Pro in debug mode...
'dar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             660ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: it will be `dart`  if i am not wrong, also how you are trying to run the app

Comment: I try to run using the run button on android studio

Comment: can you try `flutter run`  on terminal

Comment: I was run the command `flutter run` then result: `PS E:\Intern\26-light & dar theme\untitled1> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 9 Pro in debug mode...
'dar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             660ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
`

Comment: can you try `flutter upgrade -f`, f this doesnt work , you can try reinstalling flutter

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred on the path of the project: `E:\Intern\26-light & dar theme\untitled1`. The problem was caused by using spaces in the file name `26-light & dar theme`. To fix the issue, create the project in a different location without spaces in the file name.
(Avoid using special characters such as "&" in file names to prevent errors from occurring. It is best practice to use only alphanumeric characters and underscores in file names.)